# Angular2, PrimeNG, Calendar, jQuery, webpack datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui, angular, webpack, primeng

I started a project using ng-admin by akveo https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin. The PrimeNG website specifies that one needs to add jQuery ui datetimepicker and jQuery datepicker in order to use their Calendar component. I did an npm install jquery-ui --save and it installed the files. However I'm clueless on how to add the reference on the webpack file and reference it properly.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we call libraries like jQueryUi and jQuery 'broken modules' because they execute and rely on eachother in the global context. There are a few different methods to shim these kind of modules.

[Here is a list of different options](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html) (as the solution cam vary per library). I like using the `ProvidePlugin` or using alias and externals.

Comment: I'm a complete noob, can you explain the process? I've been trying to understand but webpack is hard to grasp. I have jQuery installed as a node_module. I have these lines     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'Tether': 'tether',
      'window.Tether': 'tether'
    }), in my webpack.common.js, I don't understand what these lines do, but it is similar to the configurations on the link you provided. After that, how do I include the jquery datepicker script into my angular2 app?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, without using webpack yet. The solution, for this specific message, is in fact to declare/include jQuery BEFORE primeng.
So I just moved up the html tag adding jQuery to my page(s) and it went fine after that.

I don't know how to use webpack, but if there is a declaration order, just declare jQuery (or its subscript datepicker and datetimepicker) before primeng.